# Trying to understand this perl regex bracketed character class?

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, character-class

Below is a script that I was playing with. With the script below it will print `a`

```
$tmp = "cd abc/test/.";
if ( $tmp =~ /cd ([\w\/\.])/ ) {
   print $1."\n";
}
```

BUT if I change it to:

```
$tmp = "cd abc/test/.";
if ( $tmp =~ /cd ([\w\/\.]+)/ ) {
   print $1."\n";
}
```

then it prints: `cd abc/test/.`

From my understanding the + matches one or more of the matching sequence, correct me if i am wrong please. But why in the first case it only matches `a`? I thought it should match nothing!!

Thank you.

Comment: It should not print the ``cd '' at the beginning.

Comment: @rashid When you want an explanation about a regexp, you can use [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAPE%3A%3ARegex%3A%3AExplain) module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. In the first case you match a single character from that character class, while in the second you match at least one, with as many as possible after the first one.

**First one :**

```
"
cd\            # Match the characters “cd ” literally
(              # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [\w\/\.]       # Match a single character present in the list below
                     # A word character (letters, digits, etc.)
                     # A / character
                     # A . character
)
"
```

**Second one :**

```
"
cd\            # Match the characters “cd ” literally
(              # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [\w\/\.]       # Match a single character present in the list below
                     # A word character (letters, digits, etc.)
                     # A / character
                     # A . character
      +              # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
"
```

Answer (score 3):

In regexes, characters in brackets only count for a match of **one** character within the given bracket.  In other words, `[\w\/\.]` matches exactly one of the following characters:

1. An alphanumeric character or `"_"` (the `\w`).
2. A forward slash (the `\/`--notice that the forward slash needs to be escaped, since it is used as the default marker for the beginning and end of a regex)
3. A period (the `\.`--again, escaped since `.` denotes any character except the newline character).

Because `/cd ([\w\/\.])./` only captures one character into `$1`, it grabs the first character, which in this case is `"a"`.

You are correct in that the `+` allows for a match of one or more such characters.  Since regexes match greedily by default, you should get all of `"abc/test/."` for `$1` in the second match.

If you haven't already done so, you might want to peruse [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).